# How can I convert a dataframe with all values in one column into a dataframe with multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of data from BLS that has columns corresponding to series_id, year, period, and value. The series_id for each entry is 20 characters in length, and the last two characters correspond to the type of measure (i.e. 01: All Employees, In Thousands, 26: All Employees, 3-month average change). Is there anyway to split the DataFrame into one with multiple columns (All Employees, All Employees, 3-month average change, etc.)? There are a total of 9 measures that I would want to split and there is no pattern to how often they switch to a different measure so I can't split the DataFrame every 100 entries or whatever the number would be.

The url for the data is: https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/sm/sm.data.0.Current

What the data looks like:

[image]

What I want the data to look like:

[image]

Comment: Could you indicate what the resulting dataframe should be like? it looks like a simple pivot table with a string extracted from string_id

Comment: @ansev Absolutely, thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still looking for a solution. Taking ansev's suggestion to use a pivot table:

```
df['measure']=df['series_id'].str[18:20]
df['series_id']=df['series_id'].str[:18]
dat=df.pivot_table(index=['series_id','year','period'],values='value',
               columns=['measure']).reset_index()
# To rename columns
names={'01':'All Employees','26':'All Employees, 3-month change'}
dat=dat.rename(columns=names)
```